# Bash-Command to get the current network bandwith usage and CPU Usage

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, console

I need some command line snippets to get the current CPU Usage (in percent) and the current network bandwith usage.

To get the CPU-Usage i found `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)"`
But it always give me

> %Cpu(s): 12,3 us,  3,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 83,7 id,  0,3 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st

The numbers given by this command are never changing. I tried to set the server under heavy-load and i got 83,7% idle as well.

As well i found `ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print "cpu %",s}'`
These values are changing, what looks nice, but i get values like

> 403.8
>
> 407.3
>
> 524.6
>
> 553.2

And I don't know, what these values mean
I have 4 cores in my computer so i would expect 400% CPU-Usage means all cores are on 100%
But how can I have more than 400% usage? even, if htop says the average CPU usage is about 3 - 5%

For the network traffic monitor I haven't found anything usable.
I just need the numbers in/out in kbps to use them in another program / script

Thanks a lot four your help :)

Answer (score 3):

For the network usage you could poll data directly from `/proc/net/dev`.

Comment: I get `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:08 /proc/net/dev` . Does that mean my machine isn't transfering any data right now? Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: Not sure if that was an ironic post(?), but if you `cat /proc/net/dev` you'll see stats for the devices in your system.

Comment: not meant to be ironic. Thanks for the tip on `cat ...`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

Try the command `uptime` which gives you the uptime and load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

The bandwidth can be found in the files `/sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_bytes` and `/sys/class/net/$1/statistics/tx_bytes`

You should remember the current value and look again after a second to get the current bandwidth usage.

One word regarding load: A lot of people think that CPU usage is a useful measurement. That's not correct. It's easy to have a system where many processes are waiting for data (network, disk, etc) but since they are waiting, the CPU load will be low. If you try to work on such a system, it will still feel sluggish.

So the system load is a much better meter for how "busy" your system is.

And you should have a look at tools like `atop` which monitor the system constantly and give you historical data, like the processes which hogged the CPU in the past. ([intro](http://www.gnutoolbox.com/atop/))

**EDIT** The reason why `top -bn1 | grep` always prints the same result is because you're measuring the startup of `top` itself. You need to run a monitor over an extended period of time before you can start use the values it gives you.

Comment: I agree with y our comment about CPU, as the author of AIX utility `nmon` says, ~"if you slice your CPU testing into really small segments, you'll see that a process is either at 100% on 0% CPU. The in between %s are just averages for longer periods of time". ALOS, is there a utility that calculates 'system load'? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: `uptime` prints the system load. I'm not sure how it calculates it; I guess it fetches it from `/proc` or `/sys` somewhere.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get the network speed itself? Then I have to calculate it by myself.   I know that only the CPU value does not tell you anything about working fast. But if your CPU-Load stays in 100% for most of the time, it may tell you, that the CPU is a bottleneck. As well as a fest network connection doesn't mean that you can transfer data faster (slow HDD and so on). So please give me a hint, how to get the current CPU load (average of all cores) (and pls not the 1min avg load, it's not precise enough) - Thanks

Comment: Speed is always distance over time. So your request to get the CPU load without a time doesn't make sense. At any given moment, the CPU load is either 100% or 0%. You always have to read several values and calculate the average over a certain time range. That said, `atop` does what you want. It can monitor the state of your system in a shell or extract interesting values and write them to a file.

Comment: Then I need the average load over 1 second max. I can't use atop because I can't extract the numbers displayed in htop into my bash script. Or can I do so? I haven't found this on http://www.atoptool.nl/

Comment: Use the tool `atopsar` which is part of the `atop` package. See http://www.atoptool.nl/systemreports.php Note that a one second report is often useless or gives you a wrong picture. You really have to accumulate data over a longer period of time. But you'll quickly see that when you run the command and look at the numbers.

Comment: I got this script http://colby.id.au/node/39 helping me a lot. I know, that one single "one second report" does not produce any usefull data. But when I do this 60 times a row, I get CPU-Load for one minute but so accurate that I can break down to single seconds. I don't want to use only one result of CPU measurement and interpret it. I will take hundreds of these values before I make myself a picture ;) - But thanks a lot to all